# ios - UIView to cover full screen, to cover the tabs from a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBarController and I want to add a UIView as a subview but I want that view to cover the whole screen including the tabs on the bottom.  All attempts I have done result in the view cover everything except the tabs on the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you have tried but, if you are trying to add the view from a `UIViewController` that is inside the `UITabBarController` then you should use:

```
UIView *coverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                             0, 
                   self.tabBarController.view.frame.size.width, 
                   self.tabBarController.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:coverView];
//and maybe [self.tabBarController.view bringSubviewToFront:coverView];
```

Comment: Thanks and btw the last attribute should be self.tabBarController.view.frame.size.Height.